How to extract P-values and append them to an already existing dataframe?
I am trying to write a simple code where it runs one-way ANOVA for each column, where the data looks like this:




PROTEIN A
PROTEIN B




A1
Cell 1
Cell 2


A2
Cell 3
Cell 4


B1
Cell 5
Cell 6


B2
Cell 7
Cell 8



Data:
structure(list(acc = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"D", "D"), A0A8L2QEN5 = c(130.3, 110.4, 123.3, 143.2, 110.4, 
130.5, 109.1, 106.4, 19.5, 16.9), P63018 = c(97.1, 93.4, 103.1, 
102.2, 110.9, 113, 122.7, 135.1, 60.6, 61.9), P85108 = c(99.1, 
103.5, 97.9, 89.8, 87.8, 94.9, 87.8, 96.9, 121.5, 120.7), A0A8L2R7U3 = c(95.9, 
101.1, 97.5, 96.6, 87.4, 97.9, 82.3, 103.7, 119.5, 118.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

The dataframe has 10 rows, and 300 columns. I have run ANOVA comparing Group A, B, C, etc. Unfortunately, I have to call for the summary of each ANOVA e.g. summary(anovas$PROTEIN A), which means that I have to do this manually 300 times. Is there any way to simply create a column (can be another dataframe) where P-value for the ANOVA is extracted automatically, so that I don't have to do this manually? Here is my code for the ANOVA:
    fit_aov <- function(col) {
      aov(col ~ trt, data = df_long)
    }

    anovas <- map(df_long[, 2:ncol(df_long)], fit_aov)

summary(anovas$protein2)[[1]][1,5]  yields 1 readout.

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and edit your question accordingly.

The data in the question is not in long format. Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of (wide format) dput(df[, 1:5]). This selects the first 5 columns only.

A few things here:

you have to be a little bit careful sticking things into formulas. Probably the most reliable approach is to use reformulate with the column name as the response.
extracting the p-value information from summary() is possible, but using broom::tidy() will make your life a little easier.

fit_aov <- function(col, trt = "acc") {
   f <- reformulate(trt, response = col)
   a <- aov(f, data = df_long)
   ## summary(a)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]
   broom::tidy(a)[["p.value"]][1]
}
vars <- names(df_long)[-1]
fit_aov(vars[1])  ## test on the first response before 
purrr::map_dbl(vars, fit_aov)


It seems like you could modify your function to directly extract the p-value. Something like this:
fit_aov <- function(col) {
  summary(aov(col ~ trt, data = df_long))[[1]]$`Pr(>F)`[1]
}

And then instead of using purrr::map, use purrr::mab_dbl. That would create a vector of p-values that you could then work with.

I tried doing that, but the entire list is just filled with NULL.
